# Does the given Inequality hold true for positive integers $a,b,c$?

Tags: inequality

> Does this inequality hold true for positive integers $a,b,c$ $$\frac{\left(\frac{2}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2}{(16)^2}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{b}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^2}{(16)^2}+\frac{\left(\frac{2}{c}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)^2}{(16)^2} \leq \frac{3}{16}$$

---

I was solving another Inequality problem and tried to create a chain of inequalities which may lead to the final answer. So, I want to know if the above Inequality is true or not. Also how do I verify inequalities in general? Like is there some type of tests to validate inequalities before trying to prove it? This would be much beneficial, thank you.

Comment: Looks trivial? a=b=c=1 gives max=$\frac{3}{16}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=1/a, y=1/b, z=1/c$, then our inequality is equivalent to
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x+y+z)^2\leq 3\cdot 16,$$
since $x,y,z\leq 1$, $(2x+y+z)^2\leq 4^2=16$ and hence the claim follows.